# Tracking processors broken after upgrading to Axon 4.9.2

Tags: axon, axon-framework

I upgraded Axon Framework from 4.9.0 to 4.9.2. Initially everything ran fine for couple of hours, but after that all the event processors broke down. I have around 60 event processors, mix of tracking and pooled - all stopped working.

I am using JPA storage for events on Postgres. EventStore is configured through autoconfiguration so all the defaults.

Only quick fix was to revert back to 4.9.0 currently.

I saw a related bug fix in 4.9.1 regards the gap aware token, I would assume this is the cause for this. Any suggestions to resolve this issue so I can proceed to upgrade my version still.

Thousands of error messages with the following exceptions occcurred:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given index [13664052] should be larger than the token index [13664545] or be one of the token's gaps [[]]
at org.axonframework.eventhandling.GapAwareTrackingToken.advanceTo(GapAwareTrackingToken.java:133)
at org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.jpa.JpaEventStorageEngine.fetchTrackedEvents(JpaEventStorageEngine.java:219)
at org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.BatchingEventStorageEngine.lambda$readEventData$1(BatchingEventStorageEngine.java:148)
at org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.BatchingEventStorageEngine$EventStreamSpliterator.tryAdvance(BatchingEventStorageEngine.java:289)
at java.base/java.util.Spliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
at org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.EmbeddedEventStore$EventProducer.fetchData(EmbeddedEventStore.java:262)
at org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.EmbeddedEventStore$EventProducer.run(EmbeddedEventStore.java:228)
at org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.EmbeddedEventStore$EventProducer.access$2800(EmbeddedEventStore.java:205)
at org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.EmbeddedEventStore.lambda$ensureProducerStarted$0(EmbeddedEventStore.java:149)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a 4.9.3 released with a fix soon. The fix is already merged. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Happened again unfortunately even after upgrading to 4.9.3

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given index [14316454] should be larger than the token index [14316636] or be one of the token's gaps [[]]\n\tat org.axonframework.eventhandling.GapAwareTrackingToken.advanceTo(GapAwareTrackingToken.java:133)`

Comment: You can increase the gap timeout. Although I wonder why the problem is still there. It's almost 200 events difference, do you publish a lot of events?

Comment: This is our invoice generation process which generates currently around 1400 events in short amount of time. I will try again with increased timeout.